# How to access a predefined array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing an issue with accessing the array element in [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS). I have an array:

```
$scope.salesentry = [
    {
        sales_id:'',
        product_id: '',
        product_category_id:'',
        sale_qty:null,
        sale_amount:null
    }
];
```

I want to update the `sales_id` field value on some button click like:

```
$scope.saveData = function() {
    $scope.salesentry.sales_id='10';
});
```

I'm not able to access it in the above way. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to update each `salesentry`'s `sales_id` ?

If yes you may use

```
angular.foreach($scope.salesentry, function(value, key){
    value.sales_id = 10;
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer i have one more simple issue, actually i am new to angularjs, the issue is                       `$scope.saveData = function() {
        var data1;
        salesreg.save($scope.register,function(data){
        data1=data.sales_id;
       }); alert (data1) }; `                            i am not able to access the variable data1 outside the function "save()" even though i have declared the varaible in the top scope ,in the "savedata()" function how to access the varaible

Answer (score 3):

`salesentry` is an array, so you need to access a specific element on it first using `[0]`.

So your code becomes:

```
$scope.saveData = function() {
    $scope.salesentry[0].sales_id='10';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to index the array

```
$scope.salesentry[0].sales_id = '10'
```

Also, no need for the comma at the end.